# Adding Custom Link as View Fields

Tags: views

I want to add a custom link to the View field set for linking to the "Details" part. The link should be `/event/{{ nid }}` and the result should look like the following.

[image]

I found two modules called [Custom Views Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_link) / [Views Entity Form Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_entity_form_field) that seems can implement the need but I don't know how to configure it.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Why don't do it with a contextual filter, then you don't need any additional modules.

Comment: @Jdrupal - Any example?

Comment: Try to google views contextual filters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct the href attribute yourself then you can simply add the ID field to your Views, but use the `Rewrite results` setting.

You can use the "Output as link" option where you only construct the HREF part of the link and Drupal does the rest `event/{{ nid }}` (you can lookup the correct token below under Replacement patterns).

Or you can use the "Override the output" option where you construct the entire anchor element: `<a href="/event/{{ nid }}">Details</a>`.

If you're linking to nodes that are in your views rows then you can add the Link to Content field to directly link to content, without having to construct it through NID.

Comment: If I use the `Override the output of this field with custom text`, the pattern `{{ nid }}` is not allowed. What can I do?

Comment: Use the pattern that is available. Can you update your question with that information, maybe a screenshot?